# g++.exe has stopped working (eclipse)

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-mars

Alright so I've recently decided to try c++ coding again and I would prefer the IDE eclipse. I've used it before with c++ on my windows laptop, the same one I'm using now. I already have the path variable set and I have the latest version of MinGW. I saw that there was an update to mars since the last time I had used eclipse so I updated and after that I couldn't include any standard headers. If I tried to run it would say binary file is missing and if I tried to build I got an error window with the prompt "g++.exe has stopped working". I tried uninstalling the software and then reinstalling, but after that, whenever I attempt to make a new c++ project I get greeted with the same g++ prompt. I've tried searching around on the web to find similar people struggling with this but I couldn't find anything specific to Eclipse.

I'd really appreciate it if I could get some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try download :http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/?source=typ_redirect

this version fixed bugs for c++ on Windows 8